# Can't access a database from a WCF Data Service hosted in an ASP NET App

Tags: asp.net, wcf-data-services, sql-server-2012-express

I built a WCF Data Service hosted in an ASP NET App, this Data Service offers access to a SQL Server DataBase.

I also built an app that accesses the service, i.e., accesses the SQL Database through the service.

I created a Login in SQL Server for NT Authority\Network Service with a default schema of dbo.

(Actually, I created it for NT Authority\Servicio de red, Network Service is "Servicio de red" in english)

I also executed the following in Sql Server:

```
ALTER LOGIN [NT AUTHORITY\Servicio de red] 
WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[MiniNorthwind]; 
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'NT AUTHORITY\Servicio de red'
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datawriter', 'NT AUTHORITY\Servicio de red'
GO
```

But when I run the app, I get the following error>

[image]

The error is produced when the app tries to iterate over a table (Line 48):

```
var customerOrders = new DataServiceCollection<Order>(ordersQuery);
```

What could it be?

Rafael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set [`UseVerboseErrors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.dataserviceconfiguration.useverboseerrors.aspx) from the [`DataServiceConfiguration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.dataserviceconfiguration.aspx) object passed to [`InitializeService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358710.aspx) in your service class to `true`.

```
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        // Don't let this go into prod
        config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
    }
```

You should then receive a message more helpful than "An error occurred while processing this request".

Note: I always get them mixed up, so you might need to use the [`ServiceBehavior`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehaviorAttribute.aspx) attribute to set [`IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.includeexceptiondetailinfaults.aspx) to true as well. You assign this attribute to your service class.

```
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true)]
public class FooService : DataService<FooServiceContext>
```